# HuggingFace Accelerate Model not using GPU

Tags: python, torchvision, huggingface

I am attempting to use one of the HuggingFace models [accelerate](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/index) and have followed to setup tutorial steps.

The issue i seem to be having is that i have used the accelerate config and set my machine to use my GPU, but after looking at the resource monitor my GPU usage is only at 7% i dont think my training is using my GPU at all, i have a 3090TI.

here is the command that i used to start my training

```
accelerate launch train_unconditional.py
–train_data_dir=“data”
–resolution=256
–center_crop
–random_flip
–output_dir=“output-256”
–train_batch_size=2
–save_model_epochs=5
–num_epochs=100
–gradient_accumulation_steps=1
–use_ema
–learning_rate=1e-4
–lr_warmup_steps=500
–mixed_precision=no
```

Is there maybe a library that i am missing or some other config setting i need to change, because in the accelerate documentation i can only find info about multi gpu training.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

Comment: Can you parse your `train_unconditional.py`?

Comment: when you say parse it, What do you mean?

Comment: Copy paste the content of that file in your post

Comment: My bad, it looks like you're using the CPU-only version of Pytorch, can you try to install the GPU version?

Comment: https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/blob/main/examples/unconditional_image_generation/train_unconditional.py

and this was the version of torch that i had installed.

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation to see how to install Pytorch with GPU support: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/